# RouterLink shows as normal text Angular

Tags: angular

I am new learning Angular when i am trying to add `routerLink` to my `<a>` tag
it change to text so i cant click in `<a>` tag can any one tell me where is my problem?

here is my code :
app.routes.ts

```ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';   
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
];
```

app.component

```html
 <app-navbar></app-navbar>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

navbar.component

```html
<a routerLink ='/'>Home</a>
<a routerLink ='/signup'>Signup</a>
```

app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet,HomeComponent,SignupComponent,FormsModule,NavbarComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
}
```

Comment: hi, what if you try with double quotes (") ? as routerLink = "/". Also, how are you importing your routes? Issue might be on that

Comment: @SaulMartinez thank you so much, i did try " but also it still show as text and as you see in the top this how i import my routes

Comment: HTML attributes cannot have a space between their name and the equals sign, or between the equals sign and the quoted value. Additionally, you need to use double quotes. e.g. `routerLink="/"` instead of `routerLink ='/'`.

Comment: I see you are using standalone components, so it's a project with no modules? Before Angular decided to stop the use of Modules, routes were added to the imports of the module. If you are not using modules, this would have to be done differently. It is a relatively new thing. Do you see a src/main.ts file? (in the same folder as the index.html file).

Comment: @SaulMartinez that true

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax, try :

```
<a routerLink="/">Home</a>
<a routerLink="/signup">Signup</a>
```

Or

```
<a [routerLink]="'/'">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="'/signup'">Signup</a>
```

Or

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/signup']">Signup</a>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help but i did try didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `RouterLink` to your `imports` array inside **any component that uses the `routerLink` directive** since you are using `standalone` components.  In your example it needs to be added to the `navbar.component`

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink, /* etc. */],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrl: './navbar.component.css'
})
export class NavbarComponent {

}
```

And you also need to remove the space before the `=` in your HTML when you assign a value to a attribute/directive

```html
<a routerLink='/'>Home</a>
<a routerLink='/signup'>Signup</a>
             ^ no space here
```